# Unit testing angularjs directive listening to an event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I created a directive that listens to an event and updates its content like so:

```
$rootScope.$on(event, function(e, msg) {
  vm.items = msg.data;
});
```

I wanted to create a unit test for this, I know how do I test if the directive broadcasts, but I do not know how to test of the the directive is listening.

Here is how I test if the directive is listening:

```
describe('input directive', function() {
  var ctrl,
      $rootScope;
  beforeEach(function() {
    module('hey.ui');
    inject(function($compile, _$rootScope_) {
      $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
      var elem = $compile('<m-search></m-search>')($rootScope.$new());
      $rootScope.$digest();

      ctrl = elem.controller('mSearch');

      spyOn($rootScope, '$broadcast');
    })
  });

  it('broadcasts e:input-valuechanged on change', function() {
    var inputVal = {input: 'input string'};
    ctrl.onChange(inputVal);
    expect($rootScope.$broadcast).toHaveBeenCalledWith('e:input-valuechanged', {data: inputVal});
  });

});
```

I was thinking of very stupid way of testing it, like so:

```
describe('list directive', function() {
  var ctrl,
      $rootScope;
  beforeEach(function() {
    module('hey.ui');
    inject(function($compile, _$rootScope_) {
      $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
      var elem = $compile('<ecal-list></ecal-list>')($rootScope.$new());
      $rootScope.$digest();

      ctrl = elem.controller('mList');

      spyOn($rootScope, '$broadcast');
    })
  });

  it('should listen to $broadcast', function() {

    $rootScope.$broadcast('e:input-valuechanged');

    var eventEmitted = false;
    $rootScope.$on('e:input-valuechanged', function() {
       eventEmitted = true;
       console.log(eventEmitted);
    });
    //run code to test
    expect(eventEmitted).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

How do I test if a directive is listening to a specific event?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to be listening to the `e:input-valuechanged` event before broadcasting;

```
it('should listen to $broadcast', function() {

  var eventEmitted = false;
  $rootScope.$on('e:input-valuechanged', function() {
    eventEmitted = true;
    console.log(eventEmitted);
  });

  $rootScope.$broadcast('e:input-valuechanged');

  //run code to test
  expect(eventEmitted).toBe(true);
});
```